# Concerned about the performance of PHP

Tags: php, performance, unix

I've been running some test PHP scripts in the Unix command line (using the `php` command) and I've noticed they tend to run really slowly.  The average script seems to take about half a second to run for every 12 or so lines of code.  This is very concerning.  I mean, I understand that PHP is an interpreted language and it's obviously going to run slower than something like C, but I didn't expect it to run this slow.  Imagine how slowly it's going to run if I have a script that's hundreds of lines long.  Or if I have to send the output of that script over a TCP connection.

I would like to understand why PHP seems to run so slowly in the Unix command line.  Is this something that's specific to the Unix `php` command?  Will it run faster if it's being interpreted by a web server like Apache?  And if so, why?  I don't understand why there seems to be this huge lag in PHP's performance, at least in the Unix implementation.

**EDIT:**
Okay, here's a sample of some of my code that ran slowly:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
function update_counter(){
    global $counter;
    $counter++;
}
update_counter();
echo "\$counter = $counter\n";
function update_local(){
    $local_num = 0;
    $local_num++;
    echo "\$local_num = $local_num\n";
}
function update_static(){
    static $static_num = 0;
    $static_num++;
    echo "\$static_num = $static_num\n";
}
update_local();
update_local();
update_static();
update_static();
?>
```

I understand that this code may be slower because it makes several function calls, but I've written code like this in Javascript, which is also an interpreted language, without seeing any performance lag.  I don't think it's the quality of the code that's the problem.  I should be able to use functions in my scripts without suffering performance penalties.

**EDIT:** This code took about half a second to run:

```
<?php
$x = 2;
$y = 5;
if( $x + $y < 5 )
    echo "less than 5\n";
elseif( $x + $y > 5 )
    echo "greater than 5\n";
else
    echo "equal to 5\n";
?>
```

Comment: Depends on how badly written the code you're running actually is, or what it's doing.... it's not the length of the script that make a difference to execution speed

Comment: But PHP is not an "interpreted language"..... it's compiled to bytecode in exactly the same way as something like Java

Comment: First example takes `0.0005 sec` to run; second example takes `0.0001 sec` to run (timed on my server) and rounded to 4 decimals

Comment: Note that Apache doesn't interpret anything..... it's the same engine at heart whether running through the Apache SAPI or the CLI..... looks like there's some issue with your server setup if it takes as long as you say

Comment: Odd.  Why is it taking so long to run on my Macbook?  Is PHP designed to run on servers with really fast CPUs?  Is that why it can afford to suffer such a massive performance penalty for things like calling functions?

Comment: Not particularly, if I run it on my local Windows, I get slower timings (0.0020 and 0.0041 seconds respectively for PHP 5.2; 0.0020 and 0.0216 for PHP 5.3; 0.0006 and 0.0567 seconds for php 5.4; 0.0006 and 0.0039 for php 5.5; 0.0008 and 0.0036 for php 5.6 and 0.0006 and 0.0020 for PHP 7) but nothing like as bad as you're experiencing (reversed order of your examples)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, running the code doesn't take half a second. Spawning the PHP process and compiling the code to [opcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) does take most of that time. How did you time it? And what are you intending to use PHP for?

The first time your run a script on the command line PHP will:

- Spawn a process
- Read the code from disk
- Compile the PHP code to opcodes
- Run the code

The time to spawn a PHP process is constant and will not increase with a longer script. When you run a webserver, you can run PHP in FastCGI and pass requests from your webserver to for instance PHP-FPM. PHP is in that case already running and you will not have to wait for the PHP process to start.

Also, the first time you run a script (after it is created or changed) PHP will compile the code to opcodes. These opcodes are cached. So when you run a script for the second time, it will run faster.

Finally, PHP was slow but is getting increasingly faster with each release. The new [PHP7](http://php.net/releases/7_0_0.php) release really brings a big performance improvement but you'll notice performance improvements from [5.3 to 5.4](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-benchmarks) as well.

Also note that PHP prior to version 5.5 doesn't have Opcache enabled by default.

You can check your PHP version with: `$ php -v`. You can check if you are running an opcache with: `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep opcache` (also check for the value of opcache.enable_cli)

Prior to PHP version 5.5 you would have to install the [APC extention](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php). You can check the installation with `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep apc`

To further reassure you; I am running a PHP script using PHP 5.5.9 which is capable of receiving and processing about a thousand complex json messages from a message queue per second. These messages are decoded, transformed, recoded and stored in a NoSQL database in a matter of milliseconds. PHP is no highly optimised C, but you don't need to be concerned about speed unless you are doing very resource intensive tasks. Just:

- Use a recent PHP version
- Ensure you are using opcode cache

Comment: Okay, I'm using PHP 5.3.13.  That might partially explain why it's so slow.  I also noticed my scripts tended to run faster the second time I ran them, but not if I waited for a long time between runs (maybe the bytecode gets deleted after a certain amount of time).